# Reading external xml log4j2 config file, if not exist then read internal in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, log4j2, application.properties

I have a spring boot application that uses log4j2 and it has its XML configuration file in the resources folder.

But the idea is that first the application looks for the configuration file outside the war and if it doesn't exist then take the one from the resource folder.

Is it possible to achieve this behavior?

UPDATE:
I add more detail to my query !!
The specific case I have is the following:
I have the following environment:
spring boot (2.2.4)
Java 1.8
log4j2
About Linux (CentOS)

The application.properties file (located in the resource folder) with the "logging.config" property pointing to an external log4j2.xml file (outside the WAR).

Something like this:

> logging.config = $ {DIR_PROP} /APP_NAME/config/appName_log4j2.xml

Internally, in the resources folder, I also have the same file, since in my tests Spring did not start if I did not have it.
The interesting thing is that after going to the internal * log4j2.xml, it goes to the external one thanks to the logging.config property.

**The objective is the opposite, first try the external file, if it is not go to the internal (resources folder).**

Answer (score 0):

If you specify log4j.configurationFile and the file can't be found it will generate an error and Log4j will use its default configuration.

Log4j will automatically search for files on the classpath so if you add an external directory to the classpath Log4j will search it when looking for log4j2.xml. If it doesn't find it I believe Spring's default configuration would then get used.

Have you considered using Spring Cloud Configuration? You can configure Spring Cloud Configuration so that it will look in various directories for the configuration file, thus allowing you to have an application specific file and a default. Log4j also supports composite configurations with Spring Cloud Config where you can have a common configuration along with an application specific config that overrides the common config. If this interests you look at [Spring Cloud Config Client](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-spring-cloud-config/log4j-spring-cloud-config-client/index.html).

Comment: Thanks @rgoers, i expanded my question by presenting more detail on the case.